# How to include JSPs file from another folder

Tags: jsp, include

How can include JSPs file from another folder:
My hierarchy is WebContent/WEB-INF/JSPs/..

My JSP file to be include is from `/WebContent/WEB-INF/JSPs/body/content.jsp` and the JSP file where will i include the file is `/WebContent/WEB-INF/JSPs/header/navigation.jsp`

What i tried so far is:

1. `<jsp:include
   page="../JSPs/header/navigation.jsp"></jsp:include>`
2. `<jsp:include
   page="/WebContent/WEB-INF/JSPs/header/navigation.jsp"></jsp:include>`

Comment: Was the double ".jsp" extension intended or just a typo in page="../JSPs/header/navigation.jsp.jsp"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your relative path is wrong. Use:

```
<jsp:include page="../header/navigation.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 10):

You should use jsp include tag as shown below from any jsp file.

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/JSPs/header/navigation.jsp"></jsp:include>
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/JSPs/header/navigation.jsp"></jsp:include>
```