# How do I pass a variable to a JSP snippet using an include tag?

Tags: jsp

To stay DRY, I have a simple header snippet that looks like:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
```

It contains the basic HTML header I want at the top of each page. Then, for each JSP page I create, I just include it with `<%@ include file="_header.jsp" %>` and it keeps my code nice and clean.

However, it means that every single one of my pages will have the same `<title>` attribute. Is there a way to pass a variable to the `_header.jsp` file and update the title that way? I know you can pass variables when using the `<jsp:forward>` action, but I need to use `<%@ include %>` so that it will display the rest of my page.

I can also update the title with the following JavaScript at the bottom of each custom page:

```
<script>
    document.title = "This is the new page title.";
</script>
```

but I figured there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `jsp:include` directive instead which supports parameter passing.

```
<jsp:include page="_header.jsp" >
    <jsp:param name="title" value="This is the page title"/>
</jsp:include>
```

Then in your header JSP, read the parameter as follows:

```
<title>${param.title}</title>
```

Comment: Does this work for linking to files one directory level up? I tried `/../_header.jsp` but got a `NullPointerException` for that line. I also tried `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/_header.jsp` but that resulted in an error, too.

Comment: Relative paths should work as evidenced by this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846556/how-to-include-jsps-file-from-another-folder

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I put a leading `/` on the relative file path when it should have been `../_header.jsp`.