# JSP / JasperException : File [/xyz.jsp] not found

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I've searched and can't find my scenario annoyingly.

When I run my project in Eclipse it works fine, but when I deploy (via WAR) to my production server I get the JasperException File Not Found. This only occurs for JSPs that aren't in the root folder. I'm stumped. In essence, I'm using the /secure/ context for my security filter.

FileStructure:
[FileStructure in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luZdA.png)

Web.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" 
        id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">

    <display-name>Name Here</display-name>
    <description>Description Here</description>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.example.package.AuthFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

JSP (yes this is the whole JSP for now as I'm just getting started):
*note: JSTL members are loaded in the header

```
<%@include file="/inc.header.jsp"%> <!-- file-not-found -->
<div class="m-2">

<h3>SECURE INDEX</h3>

<h5>User Details</h5>
<table class="table table-sm table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="detail" items="${user.userdetails}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${detail.key}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${detail.value}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
<%@include file="/inc.footer.jsp"%> <!-- file-not-found -->
```

Error Message:

```
Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: [1], column: [2]) File [/inc.header.jsp] not found
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:98)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:345)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:380)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:481)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1797)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:141)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:127)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:202)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:383)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

EDIT --- I found that if I do the same in an "insecure" folder it worked for a second. So there's something up that I can't wrap my mind around ... AuthFilter is so simple I don't see anything wrong with it.

AuthFilter.java:

```
package com.example.package;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
//import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

// @WebFilter("/AuthFilter") /* removed in favor of web.xml */
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

    //private ServletContext context;

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        //this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
        //this.context.log("AuthenticationFilter initialized");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        //String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        //this.context.log("Requested Resource::"+uri);
        //System.out.println("Requested Resource::"+uri);

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

        Boolean isLoggedIn = false;
        if (session != null) isLoggedIn = (Boolean)session.getAttribute("isLoggedIn");
        if (isLoggedIn == null) isLoggedIn = false;

        if( !isLoggedIn ){
            //this.context.log("Unauthorized access request");
            res.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
        }else{
            // pass the request along the filter chain
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        //TODO close any resources here
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I may be on to something.
HINT: this is a 'virtual-context' or whatever you call it. Where my http://localhost/ doesn't actually work. It has to be http://app.example.com/ to be recognized by Tomcat. I'm thinking tomcat is resolving my "secure" folder as a standalone web-app inappropriately. I have multiple virtual hosts on this system and none happen to use the  concept, nor sub-folder-index files. As I just got a new error moving my header/footer files into the /secure/ I'm now getting a "The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application" .... hence, I think Tomcat thinks my /secure/ is a standalone app.

Server.xml entry:

```
<Host name="app.example.com" appBase="webapp_hosts/app.example.com" unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="true" reloadable="true">
            <Alias>app.example.server</Alias>
            <Alias>app.example.local</Alias>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="crm_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
        <Context path="/" docBase="" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
      </Host>
```

Comment: remove the forward slash.

Comment: tried that, and ../, and /../. Nothing so far :(. Remember. If I move the file out of the /secure/ folder it works (all my other files work fine). It's just when I do the absolute path from a sub-folder.

Comment: so do you have a file named `inc.header.jsp` ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, my attached image didn't embed for some reason. Near the top you can click and see my structure.

Comment: consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846556/how-to-include-jsps-file-from-another-folder

Comment: thanks, but same same :::::: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: [1], column: [2]) File [../inc.header.jsp] not found :::::: I'm hoping to use absolute URLs for everything. Relative's are too flaky.

Comment: ok. I'm on to something. when I replicate the "secure" folder as "insecure" it works. SO..... there's something up with my AuthFilter. Like a XSS block or something. Now I have to chase that.

Comment: good skills, I hope you get to the bottom of it.

Comment: nope. actually it 'stopped' working now. bah!

Comment: updated "EDIT" near the bottom of original post. ... I think I'm on to something with the webapp deployer in Tomcat thinking my /secure/ is a standalone webapp

Answer (score 0):

You are saying, that all requests fails if you move your jsp into the secure folder. This requests will be filtered by your filter and without a look into the filters implementation a answer is very hard.

Please share the filter and listener if you can.

Comment: I have shared the filter code, and it's declaration in the web.xml. the background "login" class simply authenticates to a DB, then adds some session variables : IsAuthenticated, IsRemembered, IsLoggedIn (true/false for each). When I move the /secure/index.jsp up to /index2.jsp it displays as expected. The listener only opens my DB connections on start.

Comment: BTW: The filter is registered twice: by the annotation and web.xml

Comment: The request comes in as /secure/index.jsp and is being intercepted by your filer. If the user is logged in, the filter chain will process the request if not a redirect will be issued. There are no more filters, so this i the place where the jsp processor comes in. It tries to lookup /secure/index.jsp in your file system. After finding and transforming to a servlet, the include directive will be processed. The /inc.header.jsp will be processed and included if present. If you move it to secured folder and reflectig this change in the include directive it's not working anymore. Right?

Comment: A jsp will be transformed to a servlet with the first request. All further requests will be handled by the servlet, not the jsp anymore, until you edit the jsp again. The same applies for the included jsp. Have you tried to clean up the compiled servlets in the work folder of tomcat?

Comment: Yes I've cleaned the work-dir, and this is the target page after a successful login. In theory it holds water. As for the double registration, I tried without the web.xml reference but it didn't apply. (Latest Tomcat 9.0.12). Thanks

Comment: When registering the filter in xml you don't need the annotation. Try to show me your complete file/folder structure for the unpacked war or maybe you have a github link to your code?

Comment: I've removed the annotation and sticking just with web.xml. It seems a lot more reliable for some reason (also easier to declare the /secure/* context control). I don't have my code on GitHub, but I'll find a way to share it this afternoon. It's 'very' simple at this stage. --thanks.

Comment: updated "EDIT" near the bottom of original post. ... I think I'm on to something with the webapp deployer in Tomcat thinking my /secure/ is a standalone webapp

Comment: PS -- my file structure is posted at the top of the original post. not an image for some reason, just a link to the image. HERE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/luZdA.png

Comment: i´ve tried to reproduce your error, but i´ve had no chance - everything is working as designed. Please check if my code at https://www.justbeamit.com/y3btx is working for you.
In this minimal implementation you´ll find a secret.jsp in the secured folder which is including a second file (inc.header.jsp). I have moved all the files to several locations, but I never had an error...
Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks so much ibexit. I figured it out as a problem in my server.xml HOST entries. My solution is posted as well (I feel dumb for it, but I've learned my Tomcat lesson for the day)

Answer (score 0):

got it. came down to my Tomcat Virtual Host declarations. I had my appBase pointing to the 'main folder of each app' which caused Tomcat to think sub-folders were more apps. I've fixed it by changing my server.xml entries to:

```
<Engine name="PROD" defaultHost="WWW">
  <Host name="WWW" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="true" reloadable="true">
    <Context name="www.example.com" path="" docBase="www.example.com" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
    <Alias>example.com</Alias>
    <Alias>example.server</Alias>
    <Alias>example.local</Alias>
    <Alias>www.example.com</Alias>
    <Alias>www.example.server</Alias>
    <Alias>www.example.local</Alias>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="www_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>
  ... other hosts/subdomains
</Engine>
```

my old (WRONG) entry was : appBase="webapps/www.example.com"